# How to get value of another property via decorator in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, decorator

```
export class UmsDictionary {
    public aField = "SUPER";
    @PropertyAlias('aField')
    public dictionary = "dictionary";
}

export function PropertyAlias(name: string) {
 return (target: any, key: string) => {
   Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
     configurable: false,
     get: () => {
       return target[name];
     },
     set: (val) => {}
   })
 }
}
```

...

```
const dct = new UmsDictionary();
console.log("VALUE = " + dct.dictionary); //undefined
```

I trying to get value of property aFiled by invoking getter of dictionary property. What is my mistake? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`target` will not be an instance of the class, it will be the class itself. to access field values you will need to use `this` inside the get/set function and not use arrow functions:

```
export class UmsDictionary {
    public aField = "SUPER";
    @PropertyAlias('aField')
    public dictionary = "dictionary";
}

export function PropertyAlias(name: string) {
    return (target: any, key: string) => {
        Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
            configurable: false,
            get: function (this: { [name: string]: any}) {
                return this[name];
            },
                set: function (this: { [name: string]: any}) {
            }
        })
    }
}
const dct = new UmsDictionary();
console.log("VALUE = " + dct.dictionary); //undefined
```

Comment: Magic...  Many thanks. We may kinda inject 'this', or I don't understand...

Comment: @vicpro the `this: ..` is just a type annotation, no JS is generated for that, it's just so that TS won't complain when we index into `this`(`this[name]`) as it would if we use strict. `this` is passed in by default by the JS runtime for the getter function, it's just the way it works ..